# Array prototype not working inside imported scripts

Tags: javascript

I am importing javascript like below

```
var imported = document.createElement('script');
imported.src = 'script.js';
document.head.appendChild(imported);
```

In my script.js I have following code

```
Array.prototype.hasMin = function (attrib) {
  return (
    (this.length &&
      this.reduce(function (prev, curr) {
        return prev[attrib] < curr[attrib] ? prev : curr;
      })) ||
    null
  );
};
```

When i Just use the above code in script tag its working normally , but when i use it via appendchild method , I get following error

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #function (attrib) {
```

Comment: The error message has `#` before `function`, which isn't in the script you posted. Check your `script.js` file for a typo.

Comment: yes i know its weird , its the same function causing this error.

Comment: Is `script.js` in the same folder as the HTML? Try using an absolute URL.